# MyFaces eats my exceptions

Tags: java, jsf-2, richfaces

When I force for example an NPE in the constructor of my `@ManagedBean` then I see a nice stack trace in eclipse. But when that same error is in an action from a `a4j:commandbutton` then I only see a very limited error message in my handler code from `<a4j:log onerror=..."/>`.

Why are my stack traces and other errors captured by JSF?

Comment: Probably the NPE is being wrapped with `FacesException`.

Comment: Thank you very much for the response but I'm sorry that I don't understand the implications of your answer. Could you please explain how that happened and how I can go back to the situation that I get nice stack traces all the time?

Comment: I can see that a InvocationTargetException is used as exception.

Comment: Please, update your post to be more informative. Like you can include the code where you are forcing NPE, code in the action, and the stacktraces.

Comment: Hey you can post answer with solution and accept it.

Comment: Only after at least 8 hours. Now I'll do that :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you very much βнɛƨн Ǥʋяʋиɢ. The hint of FacesException was most helpfull. In combination with Google I was able to find that I could create my own ExceptionHandler and factory. That fixed my problem of eaten exceptions. Thank you very much!. See link: [GoJava](http://jugojava.blogspot.com/2010/09/jsf-2-exception-handling.html)